# VB.Net ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter giving error during saving solution

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls

Hello I am creating a User Control and wanted to have a custom object property ***ImageChange***.

I google this and found this link Getting the Most Out of the [.NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).

Everything seems working when I run the User Control Project, can change the property (On code or manual) and prompts its current value. But when I add the User Control to another windows form project I got an error [Please see image](https://ibb.co/gFmyDy). This error occurs when I try changing the ***ImageChange*** property and saving the project.

**Below is the code**

```
    Public Class UserControl
        Private _imageChange As New ImageChange
        Public Property OnImageChange As ImageChange
            Get
                Return Me._imageChange
            End Get
            Set(value As ImageChange)
                Me._imageChange = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    <ComponentModel.TypeConverter(GetType(ImageChangeConverter))>
    Public Class ImageChange

        Private _zoom As Boolean = False
        Private _rotate As Boolean = False

        Public Property RetainZoom As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me._zoom
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                Me._zoom = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property RetainRotate As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me._rotate
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                Me._rotate = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class ImageChangeConverter
        Inherits ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter

        Public Overloads Overrides Function CanConvertTo(ByVal context As ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal destinationType As Type) As Boolean
            If (destinationType Is GetType(ImageChange)) Then Return True
            Return MyBase.CanConvertFrom(context, destinationType)
        End Function

        Public Overloads Overrides Function ConvertTo(ByVal context As ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As Globalization.CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object, ByVal destinationType As System.Type) As Object
            If (destinationType Is GetType(System.String) AndAlso TypeOf value Is ImageChange) Then
                Try
                    Dim c As ImageChange = CType(value, ImageChange)
                    Return "{" & c.RetainZoom & ", " & c.RetainRotate & "}"
                Catch
                    Throw New ArgumentException
                End Try
            End If
            Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
        End Function

        Public Overloads Overrides Function CanConvertFrom(ByVal context As ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal sourceType As System.Type) As Boolean
            If (sourceType Is GetType(String)) Then Return True
            Return MyBase.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType)
        End Function

        Public Overloads Overrides Function ConvertFrom(ByVal context As ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As Globalization.CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object) As Object
            If (TypeOf value Is String) Then
                Try
                    Dim arr As String() = value.ToString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split(",")
                    Dim c As New ImageChange With {
                        .RetainZoom = Boolean.Parse(arr(0).Trim),
                        .RetainRotate = Boolean.Parse(arr(1).Trim)
                    }
                    Return c
                Catch
                    Throw New ArgumentException
                End Try
            End If
            Return MyBase.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value)
        End Function
    End Class
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATES**

I created a new Class Library with only objects of ***ImageChange***, ***ImageChangeConverter*** and a sample ***UserControl***. [Please see this solution](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ODApOwGe9cEm0xLiga3VFJskD-hwnvqM). I don't know if this has any help but I used Visual Studio 2017 with target .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: Your code does produce that exception.  If I rename your ImageChange and ImageChangeConverter classes, the exception goes away.  I don't have an explanation for that.

Comment: Also, that MSDN has a typo that you copied to your code.  The CanConvertTo function has `Return MyBase.CanConvertFrom(...`  That should be `Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(...`

Comment: I'm ashamed of myself :(. Yes the error is on the return. Thank you so much.